# Several RemoteConnectionManager failed attempts - Triggers restart

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

Questions: How to Change the number/time duration when
Window triggers the 'restart'. 
It seems that 700+ failed login attempts RDC is a bit much

> 01/12/2012  1:48:34 AM TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager To
>   01/12/2013    3:00:01 AM TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager There
>   were over 700 attempts to connect to
>   TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager
>
> 01/12/2012    03:05:01 AM The System begain to shut down.
>
> The process C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe (xxx4) has initiated the
>   restart of computer xxxx4 on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for
>   the following reason: Operating System: Recovery (Planned)  Reason
>   Code: 0x80020002  Shutdown Type: restart  Comment:
>
> The system went off-line at 1/12/2012 3:05:54 AM and did not
>   'restart'. We did a manual system started at system time 1/12/2012
>   6:16:08 AM

Answer (score 0):

Those two event log entries are over an hour apart. What makes you think they're related?

Chances are either your server was compromised and shut down, or someone else with remote or console access shut it down. If this is a hosted system, I'd contact your host.